# Can't run pub get for Dart. How to set PUB_CACHE on Windows 10?

Tags: dart, dart-pub

I need to build a Dart Web App project on Windows 10. 
I get this error every time I try to run pub get:

```
"Target \\storage\N-HOME\nz9\APPLICATION DATA\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\
dart_to_js_script_rewriter-1.0.1\lib of Link.create on Windows cannot be converted
to start with a drive letter. Unexpected error., path = ''"
```

I think the problem is my APPDATA is set to a virtual disk (path starts with "\STORAGE\N-HOME") because I'm using a public machine. I tried creating a system environment variable PUB_CACHE as indicated [here](https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/installing.html). But it doesn't make a difference.

Has anyone seen this problem and fixed it?

Comment: What did you set `PUB_CACHE` to?

Answer (score 2):

You can change the location by setting a `PUB_CACHE` environment variable but you'll need to restart any shells for it to take effect.

However you might find that this still won't work; I think things need to be on a local drive and currently (due to use of symlinks) your PUB_CACHE needs to be on the same drive as your app (see [Pub does't work on Windows 8 when app is on different drive than Pub cache](https://github.com/dart-lang/pub/issues/880)).